# How do I make my laptop sleep when it reaches some low battery threshold?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, suspend, battery

I'm using Ubuntu, but I have i3 as my window manager instead of a desktop environment.

When my battery reaches 0%, the computer will just abruptly shut down, no warning or anything.

Is there a simple script or configuration I can set up so that it goes to sleep at, say 4% battery?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a small script that checks for the battery level and calls a custom command, here `pm-hibernate`, in case the battery level is below a certain threshold.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

###########################################################################
#
# Usage: system-low-battery
#
# Checks if the battery level is low. If “low_threshold” is exceeded
# a system notification is displayed, if “critical_threshold” is exceeded
# a popup window is displayed as well. If “OK” is pressed, the system
# shuts down after “timeout” seconds. If “Cancel” is pressed the script
# does nothing.
#
# This script is supposed to be called from a cron job.
#
###########################################################################

# This is required because the script is invoked by cron. Dbus information
# is stored in a file by the following script when a user logs in. Connect
# it to your autostart mechanism of choice.
#
# #!/bin/sh
# touch $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
# chmod 600 $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
# env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
# echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
# exit 0
#
if [ -r ~/.dbus/Xdbus ]; then
  source ~/.dbus/Xdbus
fi

low_threshold=10
critical_threshold=4
timeout=59
shutdown_cmd='/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate'

level=$(cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_percent)
state=$(cat /sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/state)

if [ x"$state" != x'discharging' ]; then
  exit 0
fi

do_shutdown() {
  sleep $timeout && kill $zenity_pid 2>/dev/null

  if [ x"$state" != x'discharging' ]; then
    exit 0
  else
    $shutdown_cmd
  fi
}

if [ "$level" -gt $critical_threshold ] && [ "$level" -lt $low_threshold ]; then
  notify-send "Battery level is low: $level%"
fi

if [ "$level" -lt $critical_threshold ]; then

  notify-send -u critical -t 20000 "Battery level is low: $level%" \
    'The system is going to shut down in 1 minute.'

  DISPLAY=:0 zenity --question --ok-label 'OK' --cancel-label 'Cancel' \
    --text "Battery level is low: $level%.\n\n The system is going to shut down in 1 minute." &
  zenity_pid=$!

  do_shutdown &
  shutdown_pid=$!

  trap 'kill $shutdown_pid' 1

  if ! wait $zenity_pid; then
    kill $shutdown_pid 2>/dev/null
  fi

fi

exit 0
```

It's a very simple script, but I think you get the idea and can easily adapt it to your needs. The path to the battery level might be different on your system. A little more portable would probably be to use something like `acpi | cut -f2 -d,` to obtain the battery level. This script can be scheduled by cron to run every minute. Edit your crontab with `crontab -e` and add the script:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/me/usr/bin/low-battery-shutdown
```

Another solution would be to install a desktop environment like Gnome or Xfce (and change your window manager to i3). Both mentioned destop environments feature power management daemons which take care of powering off the computer. But I assume you deliberately don't use them and are seeking for a more minimalistic solution.

Comment: Hm, I tried running `sleepd -b 40` and nothing happened after the 40% mark. I also tried `sudo sleepd -b 40 -s pm-suspend` and nothing happens...

Comment: @NoamGagliardi Confirmed, it doesn't work here either. Furthermore the package seems unmaintained. I try if I can find a better alternative and update my answer, otherwise I'll delete it.

Comment: (TIL "`cut`".) The script works! I have `acpi | cut -f2 -d, | cut -f1 d%` -- I'll  read about cron to get it to run on its own. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have `/sys/devices/platform/smapi/` directory. Where can I find the remaining percentage of battery power? I am using custom kernel 3.10

Comment: @MartinVegter It depends on your hardware, you can try `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`. Otherwise use the `acpi` command.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of hacking your own scripts and if you are using Ubuntu as the tag suggests, you could just install the upower package. It should be available on all Debian derivatives including Ubuntu. By default it comes with a configuration in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` which activates hybrid sleep once the battery level reaches critical values. The default for the critical level is 2%.

For users of other distributions, the relevant entries for `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` are:

```
PercentageAction=2
CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep
```

You can also use `TimeAction` together with `UsePercentageForPolicy=false` to let the action be carried out once only the specified time is left:

```
TimeAction=120
```

The valid values for `CriticalPowerAction` are `PowerOff`, `Hibernate` and `HybridSleep`. If HybridSleep is set but not available, Hibernate will be used. If Hibernate is set but not available, PowerOff will be used.

The advantage of HybridSleep is, that in addition to writing out memory into your swap area, it then suspends the system. Suspend will still consume some battery but if you come back before the battery ran out, you can much more quickly resume from a suspended system than from a hibernated one. In case the battery does run out before you get back to a power socket, you can resume the system from hibernation once you have power again.

Comment: Note: I think `HybridSleep` requires to have a swap space.

Comment: @cipricus that is correct but upower will gracefully choose to shut the machine down instead if it cannot hibernate.

Comment: is resume automatic when the battery gets charged or does one have to manually press the power button?

Comment: @MartinMassera one has to manually press the power button

Comment: To get related info: `cat /etc/UPower/UPower.conf | grep -v "^#" | egrep "Critical|Low|Action|Time"; gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`. To get suspend/hibernate support use `pm-is-supported` from pm-utils package

Comment: Should it (editing UPower.conf) work w/out reboot? I've tried on Linux Mint and it does not. Maybe daemon restart is needed?

Answer (score 14):

As of Debian ≥ 10 (and comparably recent Linux systems), you can just create a file `/etc/cron.d/check-battery` that contains:

```
* * * * * root [ "$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)" != Discharging -o "$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)" -gt 30 ] || systemctl suspend
```

This will suspend your system whenever the battery level reaches 30%.

Of course, feel free to replace the final `suspend` with `hybrid-sleep`, `hibernate`, `poweroff` or whatever fits your needs.

No external tools are required, not even the `acpi` package. This is based on the idea of Matija Nalis' answer, but adjusted to the year 2023.

Comment: Is the [upower answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317933/66736) obsolete?

Comment: I don't know if the upower answer is obsolete or not. It just didn't work for me, and I didn't find enough time to investigate and to debug that stuff. And to put it bluntly: Why should I? This simple one-liner is doing its job well. It is **reliable** since the day I created it, with a minimum of dependencies and system requirements. The only thing I changed since then is increasing the threshold from 10% to 30%.

Comment: What do the stars mean? Why did you write them?

Comment: Every file in /etc/cron.d/ is a crontab. The 5 stars mean that the following command is to be executed every minute, and "root" is the user under whose permissions the command is to be executed. See `man 5 crontab` for more details.

Comment: note: `.../BAT0/status` maybe return `Unknown`，so it is better to use `[ "$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)" = Discharging -a "$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)" -lt 10 ] && systemctl suspend` instead.

Comment: @ipcjs Thanks for the hint. I improved my answer accordingly. Note that I'm preferring "!= Discharging" over inverting the whole logic, as the latter would make the command return with a non-zero exit code when everything is fine, which would be quite confusing.

Comment: @lucidbrot, Just now to Linux Mint 20.2 at least on the fly (w/out reboot) editing UPower.conf has not resulted in action(s) when thresholds were achieved and % decreased even further. Maybe it needs daemon restart, but help (as man page itself notices "not fully documented").

Comment: I needed to replace `/BAT0/` with `/BAT1/` on a 2022 "frame.work" laptop running Linux Mint.

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer is great, but a little bit outdated for Ubuntu 16.04:

- The commands to get battery status have changed.
- The environment variables required for notify-send to work [have changed](https://anmolsinghjaggi.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/notify-send-in-ubuntu-16-lts/).
- The script given there no longer works from user cron as hibernate requires root.
- `systemctl hibernate` is preferred over `pm-hibernate`.

So, [here](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/snippets/blob/2f07a24b23ffaeb332c38115abfdfcbfaadc79ba/snippets/auto-poweroff/auto-poweroff.sh) is the script I use:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Notifies the user if the battery is low.
# Executes some command (like hibernate) on critical battery.
# This script is supposed to be called from a cron job.
# If you change this script's name/path, don't forget to update it in crontab !!

level=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity)
status=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)

# Exit if not discharging
if [ "${status}" != "Discharging" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Source the environment variables required for notify-send to work.
env_vars_path="$HOME/.env_vars"
source "${env_vars_path}"

low_notif_percentage=20
critical_notif_percentage=15
critical_action_percentage=10

if [ "${level}" -le ${critical_action_percentage} ]; then
  # sudo is required when running from cron
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  exit 0
fi

if [ "${level}" -le ${critical_notif_percentage} ]; then
  notify-send -i '/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/status/battery-caution.png' "Battery critical: ${level}%"
  exit 0
fi

if [ "${level}" -le ${low_notif_percentage} ]; then
  notify-send -i '/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/status/battery-low.png' "Battery low: $level%"
  exit 0
fi
```

The environment variables required for `notify-send` to work are created using [this script](https://github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/snippets/blob/4ea8a564c62dca40a459205b5ade65dc6bed7306/snippets/cron/create_env_vars.sh):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create a new file containing the values of the environment variables
# required for cron scripts to work.
# This script is supposed to be scheduled to run at startup.

env_vars_path="$HOME/.env_vars"

rm -f "${env_vars_path}"
touch "${env_vars_path}"
chmod 600 "${env_vars_path}"

# Array of the environment variables.
env_vars=("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" "XAUTHORITY" "DISPLAY")

for env_var in "${env_vars[@]}"
do
  echo "$env_var"
  env | grep "${env_var}" >> "${env_vars_path}";
  echo "export ${env_var}" >> "${env_vars_path}";
done
```

This file needs to run at startup (can be done using any method of your choice; I use Ubuntu's builtin [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html)).

**Note:** `sudo systemctl hibernate` might not work from cron. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/786225/173003) to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways it could be implemented, as there are many different power managment schemes implemented depending on what you have installed.

This simple one works for me on minimalistic Debian Jessie without any desktop environment, just with small and fast icewm window manager. (It is trimmed down because is just way too slow otherwise, and this way it outperforms GNOME on much better hardware)

Specifically, I DO have installed following packages:
**acpi acpi-fakekey acpi-support acpi-support-base acpid pm-utils**
but have NONE of the following (having purged them):
**gnome* kde* systemd* uswsusp upower laptop-mode-tools hibernate policykit-1**

So I just put this in `/etc/cron.d/battery_low_check` (all in one line, split for readability):

```
*/5 * * * *   root  acpi --battery | 
   awk -F, '/Discharging/ { if (int($2) < 10) print }' | 
   xargs -ri acpi_fakekey 205
```

It is quick, low-resource-usage, and does not depend on other deamons (if fact, it will be ignored if they're active - see `/usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs` for details).

**What it does:** every 5 minutes (`*/5` - you can change to every minute by just using `*` if you need it to check battery more often) it will poll battery status ("*acpi --battery*") and execute command after `xargs -ri` only if battery is "Discharging" (that is, you're not connected to AC) and battery status is less than `10%` ("*int ($2) < 10*" - feel free to tune it to your needs)

`acpi_fakekey 205` will by default send `KEY_SUSPEND` ACPI event (like you pressed a key on laptop requesting suspend), which will then do whatever it usually does for you (configured in `/etc/default/acpi-support`) - for me it hibernates to disk.

You could use other command instead of `acpi_fakekey 205` of course: like `hibernate` (from hibernate package), `s2disk` or `s2mem` (from uswsusp package), `pm-suspend-hybrid` (from pm-utils package) etc.

BTW, magic key numbers like *KEY_SUSPEND=205* above are defined in `/usr/share/acpi-support/key-constants` (other interesting one is probably *KEY_SLEEP=142*)

Comment: that seems very nice! but could that be used with  systemd timer instead of cron? (example [here](https://solus-project.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=1051&hilit=cron#p6040)) I'm on Solus OS where cron is absent.

Comment: @cipricus I guess so, but I avoid systemd so can't give example. I do seem to recall systemd has its own ACPI power handlers, so if you're stuck with systemd you would probably want to avoid clashing with that

Comment: thanks, I have found an alternative involving `uname`: https://github.com/jerrinfrncs/batterynotif/blob/master/batterynotif%28uname%29.sh

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution, that is partly inspired by other answers: https://github.com/jerrinfrncs/batterynotif, namely the script `batterynotif(uname).sh`.

See the script here: https://github.com/jerrinfrncs/batterynotif/blob/master/batterynotif%28uname%29.sh

For my own use I have changed the script to enter hybrid-sleep instead of shut-down, by using the command `systemctl hybrid-sleep`. (Swap space is needed by this option.)