# XMobar-friendly low-battery warning?

Tags: laptop, xmonad, battery

I'm in the process of setting up a laptop running Debian Jesse with xmonad as the display manager. I use xmobar to display information about the current state of the system, including the battery level. However, I find that I forget to check regularly and I'm always surprised when my computer suddenly shuts off because the battery died --- I miss the pop-up notifications that I used to get with XFCE.

What can I use to get an attention-grabbing warning about my low battery? Most solutions I've found use dzen, or just display a number on the status bar, which I've found to be insufficient.

Comment: This might answer your question: [How do I make my laptop sleep when it reaches some low battery threshold?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84437/12779)

Answer (score 1):

This is no ready solution, but an idea: I would use `osd_cat` which comes in the package *xosd* in Fedora Linux together with a cronjob, that checks your battery status.

You can edit your cronjobs with

```
crontab -e
```

and you find your battery status in `/sys/class/power_supply/`, and there it is in my case `BAT1/` with some files `charge_now` and `charge_full`. With those files, that is with

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full
```

you could find the percentage remaining in your battery, which could then show you a big message with osd_cat (onscreen display).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short script I wrote following @erik's suggestion of using osd_cat:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now") as f:
    charge_now = float(f.read())
with open("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full") as f:
    charge_full = float(f.read())

percent = 100*charge_now/charge_full

if percent < 10:
    p = Popen(['osd_cat','-A','center','-p','middle','-f','-*-*-bold-*-*-*-36-120-*-*-*-*-*-*','-cred','-s','5'],stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(input="Battery Low!")
    p.wait()
```

which you can then run via a cron job every minute:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
PATH=/usr/bin

* * * * * python ~/power_warning.py
```