# notify-send from fcrontab not displaying notification

Tags: arch-linux, cron, notify-send

Referenced these links with no success. Most of them seem to be ubuntu, gnome, and cron syntax specific.

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/notify-send-doesnt-work-from-crontab/346580#346580
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519673/cron-with-notify-send
3. [How can I get an alert when my battery is about to die in Linux Mint?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-get-an-alert-when-my-battery-is-about-to-die-in-linux-mint)

Tried export display, dbus, full command path.

Running Arch Linux with dwm. Using fcron and fcrontab -e.

fcrontab

```
@ 5s /usr/local/shsc/battlow
```

When I call the script explicitly it works as intended (`/usr/shsc/battlow`).

Script

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

export DISPLAY=:0

battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
if [ $battery_level -le 100 ]; then
    notify-send "Battery low" "Battery level is ${battery_level}%!"
fi
```

Tried with and without the `export DISPLAY=:0`.

Verified display with

```bsh
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

```bsh
# systemctl status fcron
● fcron.service - fcron periodical command scheduler
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fcron.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-05-18 08:36:13 MST; 12min ago
   Main PID: 8778 (fcron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18916)
     Memory: 2.3M
        CPU: 3.182s
     CGroup: /system.slice/fcron.service
             └─8778 /usr/bin/fcron -b

May 18 08:48:08 bar fcron[11367]: Job '/usr/local/shsc/battlow' started for user foo (pid 11372)
May 18 08:48:08 bar fcron[11367]: Job '/usr/local/shsc/battlow' completed
May 18 08:48:13 bar fcron[11383]: Job '/usr/local/shsc/battlow' started for user foo (pid 11388)
May 18 08:48:13 bar fcron[11383]: Job '/usr/local/shsc/battlow' completed
```

Comment: You need the $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable from your logged in session.

Comment: Add a post with code.