# Accubattery for linux

Tags: android, power-management, laptop, battery

I use Accubattery **[1]** app on my Android,
to (try) improve phone's battery health over time;

I'd like to have a software like that on Linux;
**Do you know something similar?**

Basically it is a timer that remember user to disconnect
laptop from charger when reached a certain/particular battery charge level,
in order to prevent over-charging;

*e.g. when battery charging reaches 80% a notification reminds you to disconnect from charger, in order to prevent over-charging;
the same for the bottom level:

when battery discharging level gets 40%, a notification reminds you to connect the charger, in order to prevent battery-wear;*

---

**[1]** https://accubatteryapp.com/

Comment: You could use something like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-get-an-alert-when-my-battery-is-about-to-die-in-linux-mint or https://www.2daygeek.com/linux-low-full-charging-discharging-battery-notification/ or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230418/battery-monitor-for-ubuntu-20-04 and then there's this project which is unfortunately dead but must be still working: https://github.com/maateen/battery-monitor/releases

Comment: That's implemented in Gnome by default: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/notify.html.en_GB

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want to be reminded of the *laptop's* battery, or the *Android device's* battery on the laptop?

Comment: @AndrewT. I added it, see OP

Answer (score -3):

Maybe what you want like this this is batmeter99 run on linux. You can monitor and get alarm phone battry on linux.

[image: batmeter99 run on mx linux]

[image: set max level from terminal and give alarm message and audio too]

[image: audio alarm play too on android]

You can stay tune at my blog [dolarmoro](http://dolarmoro.blogspot.com/). Batmeter99 will be release soon.Its freeware with restrict for limited using for 2 months.This app indonesian language.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "reminding the *laptop's* battery*.